# landscape and portrait orientation mode issue

Tags: android, orientation-changes

I am running an application in which I'm running an audio when it is clicked on image, while audio is being played and i changed the mode from landscape to portrait or from portrait to landscape and click on image, it plays another audio clip.

*Example:*

2 audios are being played now. But this issue does not occur by clicking the images in the same mode.

Is there any way to stop the previous activity when mode is changed?

Answer (score 2):

For playing audio files just use **Service** don't play inside Activity ,so that you can stop Service so that song can be Stopped. Then you should focus on how you are going to handle your Orientation

1. Recreating Activity
2. Handle orientation changes yourself.

My best Advice is that you should handle yourself.For that you should use two thing :

1. Add
   `<activity android:name=".CurrentActivity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
    </activity>`

2.Call

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
}
```

If orientation is changed you should handle Service as you wants.

Comment: i did <activity android:name=".CurrentActivity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"> </activity> in my minifest file and @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setContentView(R.layout.kalma1);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.kalma1);         
    }
} in my class but it is disturbing my layout when i change it from one to another :(

Comment: You want to block orientation changes?

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html...  Use OonRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to save your data

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in **AndroidManifest** with the current activity where you facing problem, but this will stop your app drawables change when you change orientation, it will use the current orientation as static for both mode, but still try and let me know.

```
<activity android:name=".CurrentActivity
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>
```

Comment: It is doing the job but disturbs the layout :(

Comment: yah, dats an issue... as i told you. have you tried the all other answers too?

Comment: yes i have tried the other answers as well. all are saying the same :(

Comment: @baig772 then why dont you create another XML for landscape mode and keep it in layout-land folder for the same

Answer (score 1):

I have tried @venky's answer but my layout is disturbed :(
[image]

[image]

and for portrait
also when orientation is changed, the buttons also don't work :(

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_prt"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>







<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pause1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pause" />




    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/play1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />







    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="315dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/kalma1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/kalma1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next1"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/forward" />

</LinearLayout>
```

is my xml for portrait and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_lndscp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/kalma1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
    android:src="@drawable/kalma1" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/next1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/forward" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:src="@drawable/play" />




<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pause1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pause" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/kalma1"
    android:src="@drawable/home" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

for landscape